# Highcharts- Increase the brightness of the pie on legend mouse hover

Tags: highcharts, angular2-highcharts

Can I increase the brightness of the slice on legend mouse hover. My plnkr is below. Also can I show the value on the slice  when I mouse hover on the legend https://plnkr.co/edit/yzXLz7AIDoWa1Pzxxl4k?p=preview.

My legend is as below

```
 labelFormatter: function () {
                    return '<div class="legend-label-md row" ><span class="col-md-8">' + this.name +
                    '</span><span class="col-md-1" >' + this.value +
                    '%</span></div> ';
                },
```

Comment: Overwrite ```.highcharts-series-hover``` with your CSS values

Comment: Is there a way to show tool tip on legend hover

Comment: Yes, you can use custom events and start tooltip with: chart.tooltip.refresh(chart.series[0].data[0]), live example: https://jsfiddle.net/jxdvd1cf/